# Find area above sine wave from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

I need a way to find the area above $y=\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ and under $y=0$. I'm making a game where there are trenches that are sine waves and I need to find the area of them to fill it with enough water.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Aaron I mean under y=0 too

Comment: Between $y=-2$ and $y=0,$ over a full cycle of the sinusoidal curve, exactly half the area is under the curve and half is over the curve by symmetry. No calculus required.

Comment: @DavidK So the area is just $2\pi$

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine flipping the graph so it is above the x-axis. It should look like this:

[image]

Now, this is the graph of $y=-\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1$, within the domain of $\left\{0<x<2\pi\right\}$. So, the desired integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(-\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1\ \right)dx$$

This integral isn't particularly difficult to solve, but since you don't have to show your work, simply use Desmos Graphing Calculator or [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5B-sin%5C%2840%29x%2BDivide%5B%CF%80%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2B1%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D):

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(-\sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+1\ \right)dx≈6.28$$

Which is your desired area.

Comment: I got $2\pi$ by multiplying the wavelength by the height of the wave and dividing it by 2 because exactly half is above and below

Comment: That works too. Did you get the same answer?

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.